# Как с много повторяющегося кода на js+jquery сделать функцию и вызывать её в нужном месте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот код, который нужно как-то объединить в функции потому что подобных блоков будет много, а я не могу понять, как это все слепить в функцию

```
nameFscrn.blur(function(){
        if(nameFscrn.val() != ''){
                if(nameFscrn.val().search(patName) == 0){
                    nameFscrn.removeClass('invalid').addClass('ok');
                }
                else{
                    $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                    nameFscrn.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
                }
            }else{
                $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                nameFscrn.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
            }
    });

    nameClb.blur(function(){
        if(nameClb.val() != ''){
                if(nameClb.val().search(patName) == 0){
                    nameClb.removeClass('invalid').addClass('ok');
                }
                else{
                    $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                    nameClb.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
                }
            }else{
                $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                nameClb.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
            }
    });
```

Comment: Напишите ваш вопрос более развёрнуто. Ваш код нам ни о чём не говорит. Мы не понимает, что вообще нужно.

Comment: анонимную функцию поименуйте да и все дела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function a(el){
    el.blur(function(){
        if(nameFscrn.val() != ''){
            if(el.val().search(patName) == 0){
                el.removeClass('invalid').addClass('ok');
            }else{
                $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                el.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
            }
        }else{
            $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
            el.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
        }
    });
}
a(nameFscrn);
a(nameClb);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function gg(){
if(nameFscrn.val() != ''){
                if(nameFscrn.val().search(patName) == 0){
                    nameFscrn.removeClass('invalid').addClass('ok');
                }
                else{
                    $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                    nameFscrn.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
                }
            }else{
                $('.notify').addClass('error').text('Введите имя в одном из следующих форматов: Имя, Фамилия Имя, Фамилия Имя Отчество');
                nameFscrn.removeClass('ok').addClass('invalid');
            }

}


nameFscrn.blur(function(){
gg();
    });
```

А если у тебя это объекты nameFscrn, nameClb то лучше сделать выборку по ним и использовать foreach или each.